# How to turn a string into an array?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

Assuming I have a string like this:

```
$x = "abc"
```

I want to know, How can I turn it into an array like: `("a","b","c")` ???

Currently I use something like:

```
$x -split ""
```

But that gives me an array like: `("","a","b","c","")` with an empty element before and after the other ones...

I can circumvent this doing `$x -split "" -ne ""`, but that seems kind of weird. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the string to a character array is probably the simplest way to go about this:

```
PS C:\> $x = 'abc'
PS C:\> $x
abc
PS C:\> [char[]]$x
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`System.String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```powershell
PS > $x = "abc"
PS > $x.ToCharArray()
a
b
c

PS > ($x.ToCharArray()).GetType()

IsPublic     IsSerial     Name     BaseType
--------     --------     ----     --------
True         True         Char[]   System.Array
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression to filter out the beginning and end of the string:

```
PS > $x -split "(?<!(^|$))"
A
B
C
PS >
```

Hope this helps
/Fridden